# Getting "name" instead of name value from rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a structure in my app where each `blog` entry is associated with a `pillar`.  On my `blogs#show` I have the following definition:

```
@pillar = Pillar.where(id: @blog.pillars_id)
```

Yet, when I go on a blog page and I try to access `@pillar.name` I get "Pillar" instead of the pillar name (e.g. "General Information" or "Financing Your Home Purchase").  When I debug and ask the error page for `@pillar` it displays the following:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Pillar id: 2, name: "Financing Your Home Purchase", buyer: true, seller: false, active: true, menu: false, snippet: "Another test snippet.  Should I be thinking wittil...", description: "It is our choices Harry that show what we truly ar...", created_at: "2018-07-03 16:50:55", updated_at: "2018-07-03 16:50:55">]>
```

If it helps, a `blog` `belongs_to` a `pillar`, and a `pillar` `has_many` `blogs`.

Can anyone figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@pillar = Pillar.where(id: @blog.pillars_id)
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not a `Pillar`. You can try:

```
@pillar = Pillar.where(id: @blog.pillars_id).first
```

or

```
@pillar = Pillar.find_by(id: @blog.pillars_id)
```

You could also do:

```
@pillar = Pillar.find(@blog.pillars_id).
```

But, that will throw an error if there is not a `Pillar` with the specified `id`.

(Are you sure it's `pillars_id` and not `pillar_id`?)

Buy why not do:

```
@pillar = @blog.pillar
```

in your controller - since you presumably have your associations set up correctly. Then you can use `@pillar.name` in your view.

Or, in your view you could do:

```
@blog.pillar.name
```

I don't particularly like `@blog.pillar.name` in a view (because your view has to know a lot about `Blog` and `Pillar`). Even using `@pillar.name` in your view means that your view has to know something about `Pillar` (specifically, that is has a method called `name`). I think I would rather do:

```
@pillar_name = @blog.pillar.name
```

in your controller and use `@pillar_name` in your view. Then your view doesn't have to know anything about `Blog` or `Pillar`.

In that case, your controller knows quite a bit about `Blog` and `Pillar`. You *could* do

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def pillar_name
    pillar.name
  end
end
```

Now, in your controller, you could do:

```
@pillar_name = @blog.pillar_name
```

In which case your controller knows something about `Blog`, but nothing about `Pillar`.

But, `Blog` still has to know about `Pillar`. So, you could do:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :piller_name, to: :pillar
end
```

and

```
class Pillar < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias pillar_name name
end
```

so that `Blog` knows very little about `Pillar`.

Also, see the comments for a really good suggestion from @spike, something like:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, to: :pillar, prefix: true
end
```

Then, you can ignore modifications to `Pillar`.

Comment: I'm not sure `alias pillar_name name` is all that common. I'd probably do `delegate :name, to: :pillar, prefix: true` which creates a method called pillar_name.

Comment: @spike - Good call. I was thinking there was something like that, but couldn't dredge it up. What happens if `Blog` also has `name`? Rails knows how to sort it out?

Comment: If you didn't use `prefix: true` then whichever gets defined last sticks, I believe. With prefix: true they're unrelated to each other. Another useful argument is `allow_nil`

Comment: @spike - Thanks! I'll have to try and keep that all in the buffer somewhere.